# How to update a chrome extension badge with data from an API on every new tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to keep a badge updated with data from an API. I was able to update the badge with the script in `popup.html`, but I cannot do it via `background.js`

Manifest includes:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
```

If I open the extensions popup which calls a .js file that works Ok, and this is the code in that .js file:

```
$.getJSON('url', function(data) {
    var downloads = data.downloads;
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:downloads});
});
```

But I tried this in `background.js` and it hasn't worked

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab) {
    fetch('url').then(response => {
      let data = response.json();
      var downloads = data.downloads
      chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({"text":downloads});
    });
});
```

I omitted the function that rounds numbers, so they fit the badge but I've taken that into account.

What am I doing wrong, could you advise me?

Comment: `response.json()` is a `Promise`, not the response. You need another `then()` on it. Also, you may want to specify `tabId` in setBadgeText(), see the documentation for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue, there was a problem with how I was using fetch. Found [this resource](https://codetogo.io/how-to-fetch-json-in-javascript/) that helped me fix it.

New background.js code looks like this

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId,changeInfo,tab) {
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      var downloads = data.downloads;
      chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:downloads});
    })
    .catch(console.error);
});
```